# Hago un git clone y me aparecen archivos para commitear

Tags: git, github, git-bash

que tal? Tengo el siguiente problema: Estoy descargando un repositorio de github a mi maquina local, realizo el git clone sin problemas, pero inmediatamente (sin siquiera abrir el codigo) hago un git status y me aparecen archivos para commitear. 
Luego intento ver el repositorio y no me aparecen los archivos actualizados.

Alguna recomendación?
Gracias

[image: git status]

Comment: solo hiciste git clone?

Comment: Revisaste que cambios se hicieron en los archivos? Puede que tu configuración de line endings esté haciendo cambios al clonar los archivos.

Comment: Intenta borrando la carpeta .git que está oculta. Ahí está el corazón de git.

Comment: @DiesanRomero si borra la carpeta .git pierde todo el repo, es como si hubiera bajado sólo los archivos y no su historia, eso no soluciona el problema.